# animationDuration() dinámico

Tags: javascript, css3

Necesito que una animación en concreto aumente la duración de la animación por medio de un clic a un botón.

Por ejemplo así sería estática: **animation-duration: 3s;**

```
#image-background {
   animation-name: image-background;
   animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-timing-function: linear;

}
```

Dinámica sería así:

```
// Velocidad.
var plus = document.getElementById('plus'); // Botón.
var view = document.getElementById('image-background'); // Animación
var i = 0; // Contador de clics.
plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
    i++;
    var value = i + 's';
    try {
        view.animationDuration = value; // IE
        view.MozAnimationDuration = value; //Moz
        view.WebAnimationDuration = value; // Chrome & Safari}
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    } finally {
        let speedInfo = document.querySelector('.speed');
        speedInfo.innerHTML = i;
    }
});
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal para que **value = i + 's';** no realice su función de incrementar la velocidad de la animación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución:

```
// Velocidad.
var plus = document.getElementById('plus'); // Botón.
var i = 10; // Contador de clics.
plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
i--;

if (i < 1) { // Evita que siga el decremento.
    return false;
}
var value = i + 's';

try {
    document.getElementById('image-background').style.animationDuration = value; // IE
    document.getElementById('image-background').style.MozAnimationDuration = value; //Moz
    document.getElementById('image-background').style.WebkitAnimationDuration = value; // Chrome & Safari}
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
} finally {
    let speedInfo = document.querySelector('.speed');
    speedInfo.innerHTML = i;
}
});
```

El problema estaba en que **i** no podía incrementarse, ya que a mayor el numero menor es la velocidad, y a menor a la inversa, así que la solución está en comenzar en 10 y terminar en 1.

Para mejor funcionamiento le asigne un condicional para que cuando llegase a uno parase.

El botón de decremento sería lo mismo pero mas corto, no lo reflejo en el código.

Comment: Buen trabajo!!!

Comment: @rnd Gracias ;)